# PySpark partitionBy, repartition, or nothing?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So what I've done is

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: enumerate(x))
```

Making keys 0-49 for my data. Then I decided to do:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: enumerate(x)).partitionBy(50)
```

I noticed something odd happening, so for the following File Size that a 10GB took 46 seconds to do my calculations and a 50GB file took 10mins 31seconds. I checked the file and for some reason it was only in 4 blocks.

So what I did was changed:

```
sc.textFile("file", 100)
```

I removed the partition by and the 50GB file dropped down to about 1 min. I was wondering if it still makes sense to try and re partition the data after it loads? Maybe by key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you ask when you need additional repartition. First, you should remember that repartition is an [expensive operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations). Use it wisely. Second, there is no rigorous answer, and it comes with experience. But some common cases are:

1. You can try to call `repartition` on your date before `join, leftOuterJoin, cogroup...` Sometimes it can speed up computation.
2. You `flatMap` your data into more "heavy-weighted" data and encounter `Java heap space Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Then you certainly should make your partitions smaller to fit the data after `flatMap`.
3. You load data into database\mongoDb\elasticSearch... You call `repartition` on your data, then inside the `forEachPartition` code block you make bulk insert of all this partition into database. So the size of these chunks should be reasonable.